# Set max width for each line or insert a line break in a section of text in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a h2 on a slider being populated from a Wordpress post title. Part of that title is a trademark, so I want that to be all on one line, with `Welcome to` on the line above.

Currently I have...

`Welcome to The Happy Foundation`

I want...

`Welcome to
The Happy Foundation`

Using max-width in css I can achieve...

`Welcome to The
Happy Foundation`

or

`Welcome to
The Happy
Foundation`

Is there a way to set a max-width for each line, or otherwise get a line break after `Welcome to` using css?

I have tried a few tricks out there like making the text transparent and adding it back in with content. But this creates all sorts of issues with alignment and also resizing on mobile browser. I don't want to over think it.

Edit: As mentioned above, the text on the slider originates from a Wordpress post title. I can't edit the original text/html markup without changing the post title. Even if I did I can't add selectors.

Edit 2: Adding a `&nbsp;` (With Option+Shift+Space on OSX) worked but threw out the alignment of my text-align center. I need the text to be centered. Or it just looks skewed anyway and is no good to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with a `<br/>` after `Welcome to` ?

Comment: I went off on a tangent with the other answers, figured this out myself and then came back to see you had it right in the first place. I think it might have been because yours was so brief and I thought you were suggesting I add that to the HTML markup, which I couldn't access , it being Wordpress.

Comment: Anyone else coming here... this simply means adding <br /> where you want a break to show up, in the post title itself. i.e. `Welcome to<br/>The Happy Foundation`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unbreakable spaces inside `The Happy Foundation`: http://jsfiddle.net/nusa3y03/

Edit: you don't even have to know `max-width` if you add an unbreakable space between `Welcome` and `to`: http://jsfiddle.net/nusa3y03/1/

Comment: I just used [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) to make the only line break opportunity after `to`. Setting the width to 0 ensures the line will break only here.

Comment: Do you use that in place of the space or adjacent to it?

Comment: Adding &nbsp; to the Wordpress post title does nothing. I think it's stripped.

Comment: You can copy the fiddle's `<h2>` content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79402/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-matthecat).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using the `max-width` property

```css
h2{max-width:236px; color:red}
```

```html
<h2 id="p1">Welcome to The Happy Foundation</h2>
```

Comment: The text originates from a Wordpress post title. I can't edit the original text/html markup.

Comment: @square_eyes but you can add css to it? possible?

Comment: I can edit anything, the stylesheet or the post title. I just don't know how I would add the P1 and P2 from your example, because the text comes from the post title.

Comment: It does not work in your example. "The" is on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has the ability to break lines based on the width of the containing element - without wrapping the text you want to treat differently within a different element, such as a span tag, it's hard to specify how those sections of your content should be treated.

The easiest solution IMO for your case is to manually add a line break to the title. However, if you'd like to try using non-breaking spaces [http://blog.liveeditorcms.com/html-tip-keeping-some-words-together/][1] to keep the title of the foundation together, try giving this a shot:

```
`Welcome to The&nbsp;Happy&nbsp;Foundation`
```

This will treat your foundation's title as if it's one word, preventing it from being broken up onto different lines. This might cause issues in the future depending on how you display on smaller screens.

Comment: As the text comes from a Wordpress post title, I can't add a line break without it being stripped. Adding a &nbsp; (as @MatTheCat said, Option+Shift+Space in OSX) will add the &nbsp;, but another unwanted outcome is that my text align centered title now gets skewed because the centering of text is based on container width.